# How can I perform click outside the input field using protractor for angular 2 e2e test?

Tags: angular, protractor

I am new to end to end test test and protractor.can anyone help me?

Comment: Hello welcome to SO. Before putting question on this site please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask link and understand how to question.

Answer (score 0):

You should define what element precisely you want to click as you say outside the input field.